# "users" link lands on the answer page

Tags: bug, api-v2.2, documentation

On the [`/users/moderators`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/moderators) documentation site, the following link is wrong:

> This method returns a list of [users](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/answer).

The `users` link mistakenly points to the *answers* object instead of to the *users* object.